# Last year my timing chain had broken

Tags: engine, pontiac, valve-timing, cylinder-head

I have a 2003 Pontiac Sunfire

A tooth broke on a sprocket and my timing chain broke.  I was told I have a bent valve and would need a new cylinder head.  It's has been sitting for exactly a year.

What precautions should I take before attempting to drive again?

Comment: Did you get it repaired already and are asking about future precautions, or are you asking about getting it repaired and back on the road?

Answer (score 3):

As Brian commented, your question and the information we have is a little vague.

Not repaired already:
It won't drive at all if the timing chain is broken. No amount of cranking the engine will start it. For this year/make/model it would probably be cheaper to either purchase another vehicle or swap in a low mileage engine than repair the current one.

If the engine has been repaired already:

- Perform maintenance as required.
- Keep away from too high of RPMS or 'redline'.
- Don't 'bounce' off of the REV limiter; this is extremely harsh on the timing components.